# Write dynamic sql query in JDBC Batch Item Writer

Tags: spring-batch

I have a job that consists of reading data from collections in MongoDB and Write it into SQLServer.

Since collections do not have the same field names, i have to set the query dynamically in the JDBC Batch Item Writer Without POJOs because of the number of collections where it is over 100 and each collection has documents having over 50 fields on average.

I tried to use org.bson.Document instead of POJO and a class that implements FactoryBean to write the sql.But it doesn't work.

To summarize, here is sample of the job:

```
//Step Configuration

 @Bean
    public MongoItemReader<Document> Reader() {
        MongoItemReader<Document> reader = new MongoItemReader<>();
        reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
        reader.setCollection("COLLECTION");
        reader.setTargetType(Document.class);
        reader.setQuery("{}");
        reader.setSort(new HashMap<>() {{
            put("_id", Sort.Direction.ASC);
        }});
        reader.setPageSize(1000);
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlString sqlString(){
       return new SqlString()
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Document> writer() throws Exception {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Document> Writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        Writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        Writer.setAssertUpdates(true);
        Writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new TableSourceProvider());
        Writer.setSql(sqlString.getObject());
        return Writer;
    }


// Sql Configuration

public class SqlString implements FactoryBean<String> {

    private String table;
    private String schema;
    private Document document;

 
    @Override
    public String getObject() throws Exception {


    
        final StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO " + schema + "." + table + " ");

        CopyOnWriteArraySet<String> keyset = (CopyOnWriteArraySet) document.keySet();

        final Iterator<String> iterator = keyset.iterator();

        String entry = iterator.next();
        final StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder("(" + entry);
        final StringBuilder value= new StringBuilder("(" + entry);
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            entry = iterator.next();
            key.append(",").append(entry);
            value.append(",").append(entry);
        }
        key.append(")");
        value.append(")");

        sql.append(key.toString());
        sql.append(" VALUES ");
        sql.append(value.toString());
        
        return sql.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return null;
    }
}

//ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider

public class TableSourceProvider implements ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Document> {
    @Override
    public SqlParameterSource createSqlParameterSource(Document document) {
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : document.entrySet()) {
            map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return new MapSqlParameterSource(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the dynamism you are looking for. However, you need to have the same field/column names between the collection and the target table. Is this the case?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine yes exactly. The names are going to be the same in jdbc target table.

Comment: The reason your approach is not working is that the `SqlString` bean is trying to get field names from the a document (I don't see how that `private Document document` is initialized btw) which is an item, and this will happen only at runtime, not configuration time. So the `SqlString` should be step-scoped as well as the writer bean. I will add an answer with how I would approach that case.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, that's right actually so i tried statically typing the sql query with some field names and parameters, it reurned an error about jdbc named parameters. Do you think your proposed solution would solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would create two steps for this case:

- Step 1 : a simple tasklet that calculates the fields required to create the sql query and put the query in the job execution context
- Step 2: a chunk-oriented step with a step-scoped writer bean configured with the sql query from the execution context.